# Playing Flash swf files in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

Is this possible? It would be great..

I've tried:

http://fci-h.blogspot.kr/2007/06/how-to-play-flash-swf-inside-c.html

which gives me a `attempted to read protected memory` error

and

http://blog.debreuil.com/?p=35

which I just can't work out how to use - I just want the code to play a **.swf** file I've made already in my XNA game.

I would just love to be able to do cutscenes or live backgrounds in this way, especially if they can be streamed from file instead of preloaded.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but this is not possible without extreme hard work that's just not going to be within your reach. (Or some painfully awkward method, like embedding a Webpage below your game)

On the bright side - there's pretty much no need for .swf embedding. Anything flash can do, XNA can do better!

Use animated images or videos for live backgrounds / cutscenes - or program them yourself in XNA using manipulation of static images - if you need help with that, post a new question asking for help with some specific thing you need done.

Also, if you want, you can ask for help converting Flash Actionscript to its C#/XNA equivalent - it can be done without too much work by anyone with a little experience in both languages.

Comment: Thanks @mcmonkey4eva. What video format would you reccomend and how would you convert pngs into it? Is it possible to stream the video rather than loading it into memory at game startup?

Comment: Depends - for cutscenes and such where you might have large long videos, you can use the [VideoPlayer](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/video-playback) class - unfortunately, this can't stream. 
OR for simple background loop 'videos', you can just put the png's in a content folder, load them all, then render them in order, slowly incrementing a variable to change which one you show. - also, regardless of how you choose to do it, you can cut down startup loading times by only loading videos/texturesets just before when you plan to actually render them, instead of at startup.